# Why UITableViewCell highlighted color in edit mode is not shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView when it is in Edit mode, cells selected gets its background highlighted but the highlighted colors I assigned to the labels on the cell does not get applied in the edit mode despite it works fine in the selection when in the ordinary mode.

```
UILabel *desc = [[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.textXStart, descYStart, self.descWidth, descHeight)]autorelease];
desc.lineBreakMode = self.descLineBreakMode;
desc.font = font;
desc.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
desc.numberOfLines = self.descLinesNumber;
desc.text = descText;

desc.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

then I add it to the cell content view

In the ordinary case the highlighted color gets showed but when I click on the edit button and select a cell the label text does not have the highlighted color.

What do you think is the reason for this issue.

Comment: Can you post more of the surrounding code? I just tried pasting that code into a project (removing the bits to set font, alignment, number of lines) and it seemed to work 100% fine. My table is set to allow single selection during editing. Try building a new project with just the minimal behavior (a single view with a single table, and code to add a label with a hilightedTextColor) and see if you can replicate the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same issue. What worked for me was to override didSelectRowAtIndexPath and didDeselectRowAtIndexPath amd set the color of the labels in my custom cell manually.

Also you need to make sure you call reload data when you go into and out of editing mode.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DocumentCell *cell = (DocumentCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if([cell isEditing]) {
        cell.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.tagsLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DocumentCell *cell = (DocumentCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if([cell isEditing]) {
        cell.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.tagsLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have set `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` to `YES`, then `UITableView` "does not query for editing styles when it goes into editing mode", as mentioned in the Class Reference:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing